# add XY to vector layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, kmz, xy

I added KMZ data (points) in QGIS using 'add vector layer'. 
Points shows up at the right location. 
However, when I use Vector-GeometryTools-Export/AddGeometryColumns, it shows error and doesn't add X Y (lat long) to the attribute table.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Try saving as shp first, then add the geometry columns to the shp. If needed, then you can export as kmz again.

Comment: Algorithm Export/Add geometry columns starting...

-2147483647 See log for more details

Comment: Abve is the error. I converted to .shp but sill doesnt work. Any other option to add XY

Comment: What happens when you open the field calculator, add a new real field named X (length 20, accuracy 5) and just type $x into the expressions-field? Same for Y with $y.

Comment: I tried 'save vector layer as CSV' with layer options - Geometry: AS_XY. It gave me an attribute table with XY. Then I used XY Tools to save this attribute table to point shape file. It worked! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Just make sure the coordinates are correct. And for statistical reasons here on stack you should mark the questions as answered, thanks.

Comment: Where do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: Right below the "vote" buttons on each answer below your questions, there is the possibility to mark the specific answer as helpful/correct.